# What property was used in this sine transformation?

Tags: trigonometry

I have this expression:

$$
ψ(χ) = A\sin^3(\frac{πχ}{α})
$$

And somehow the book i read equalizes the previous equation to this one:

$$
ψ(χ) = \frac{A}{4}[3\sin(\frac{πχ}{α}) - \sin(\frac{3πχ}{α})]
$$

What trigonometric identity was used to make this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identity is 
$$\sin^3x=\frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{4}$$
 Proof:
\begin{align*} 
 4\sin^3x-3\sin x &=  \sin x(4\sin^2x-3)
 \\ 
 &=\sin x(1-4\cos^2x) \quad \text{Pythagorean identity} 
\\ 
 &=\sin x(2\cos^2x-\cos(2x)-4\cos^2x) \quad \text{Double angle cosine} 
\\ 
 &=-\sin x(2\cos^2x+\cos(2x))
 \\ 
 &=-[(2\sin x\cos x)\cos x+\sin x\cos(2x)]
\\ 
 &=-[\sin (2x)\cos x+\sin x\cos(2x)]\quad \text{Double angle sine}
\\ 
 &=-\sin (2x+x)\quad \text{identity sum sine}
\\ 
 &=-\sin(3x)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

By DeMoivre's identity,

$\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^3=$

$\cos^3(x)+3i\cos^2(x)\sin(x)-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)-i\sin^3(x)$.

Grouping the imaginary terms together, we see that $\sin(3x)=3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)-\sin^3(x)$.

We can rewrite $3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)$ as $3\sin(x)(1-\sin^2(x))$, which gives us $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$.

Finally, we can write $\sin^3(x)=\frac{1}{4}(3\sin(x)-\sin(3x))$.

Comment: +1 for demoivre